# Sending JS variable via href link

Tags: javascript, html, href

I am trying to send a JS variable to a particular webpage.Below is my code.

```
<script>
function hello()
{
var data="hello";
<a href="www.mytestsite.com?var="' +data +'>Send now</a>
}
</script>
```

The function hello() gets called when a submit button is clicked by the user.But when I click on the link "send now".This is the result `www.mytestsite.com?var=`.That is data is not getting appended to the link.What I am going wrong in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot simply embed an anchor tag in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java script code is invalid.
It should be something like that:

```
   <script>
    function hello()
    {
          var data="hello";
          document.write('<a href="www.mytestsite.com?var='+data+'">Send now</a>');
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the javascript is only executed on a button click, and you want to redirect the user, you do not need an anchor tag. Just redirect the user.

```
function hello() {
  var data = "foobar";
  window.location.href = "http://example.com?data=" + data;
}
```

Comment: I want to redirect the user when they click on "send now link"  and not on the button click.

Comment: Then set the event handler on the link, and set the href for the link to `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
function hello()
{
   var data="hello";
   document.write("<a href='www.mytestsite.com?var=" + data + ">Send now</a>");
}
</script>
```

or if you want to put the link with in some html element

```
document.getElementById('DIV').innerHTML = "<a href='www.mytestsite.com?var=" + data + ">Send now</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `function(like hello())` on `onclick` attribute of anchor tag:

```
onclick="yourFunction();return false;"
```